# Hibernate 4.3 loads all hbm files even if they're not declared in persistence unit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to configure a test for hibernate 4.3 with JPA and Spring 4 using the following config:

```
<bean id="em" class="LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
            <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
                  <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" />
            </property>
    <property name="persistenceXmlLocation"
        value="classpath:integrations/hibernate4/jpa/persistence.xml" />
</bean>
```

Now the persistence config looks as follows:

```
<persistence-unit name="test" >
    <class>hibernate4.jpa.JpaEntity</class>
    <class>hibernate4.jpa.JpaHiLoEntity</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />
    </properties>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
</persistence-unit>
```

If I run the above with hibernate 4.2.4 everything runs fine, however with 4.3 the above setup loads ALL hbm.xml resource files, some of which refer to classes that are not present on the classpath, causing `ClassNotFoundException`.

Does anyone know what the reason for the changed behavior is and how to stop hibernate from scanning for hbm.xml files (packagesToScan property did not work either)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into this problem as well. The ***hibernate.archive.autodetection*** property controls what Hibernate will automatically scan for:

1. If the property is undefined, hbm files will be included, and annotated classes will be included unless `<exclude-unlisted-classes>` is set to true.
2. If the value of the property contains "hbm" then .hbm.xml files will be included. Otherwise they won't be.
3. If the value contains "class", then any annotated classes on the classpath will be included. Otherwise they won't be.
4. If the property is defined at all, regardless of its value, it affects the behavior of Hibernate. See the org.hibernate.jpa.boot.scan.internal.StandardScanOptions constructor.

For my purposes, I needed the persistence unit to include only the entities that were explicitly listed in `<class>` elements. To accomplish this, I defined the property with a value of "none":

```
<persistence-unit name="num2" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    ...
    <properties>
        ...
        <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="none" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

Unfortunately, the only documentation I could find on this property was for the [stable release](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html#setup-configuration-packaging), whatever that is.  There was no mention of it in the docs for Hibernate 4.3, but that is the version I use and I can confirm the property works.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can also configure the bean `em` without using the file `persistence.xml`. e.g.:

```
<bean id="em" 
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean" 
      p:dataSource-ref="dataSource" 
      p:packagesToScan="···.model">

    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter" 
              p:showSql="false" 
              p:databasePlatform="org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServerDialect" />
    </property>

    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>

</bean>
```

Answer (score 0):

The `exclude-unlisted-classes` doesn't work if your class is in the packages to scan, e.g. you want to have it registered, but doesn't want the hbm.xml for it.

I fixed that using hibernate property `hibernate.archive.autodetection` set to `class`, making Hibernate scan only classes and not mapping files.

```
<properties>
    <property name="hibernate.archive.autodetection" value="class" />
</properties
```